# IIS module, HttpRequest read message body

Tags: c#, .net, iis, module

Is there a way to get message body from [HttpRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.90).aspx) using C#? URI and other top level attributes are available such as headers but not message body.

While writing an IIS module I need access to the message body to be able to do event recording and other actions (authorization etc). We have access to [HttpApplication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication(v=vs.110).aspx) with a [HttpContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx), however I am unable to find a way to read the message body from any sort of request.

Any tips are welcome in the IIS module space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var _request = ((HttpApplication)sender).Request;

 var _bytes = new byte[_request.InputStream.Length];
 _request.InputStream.Read(_bytes, 0, _bytes.Length);
 _request.InputStream.Position = 0;
 string content = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_bytes);
```